# Proper way of handling flash messages within filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a situation where a user is able to research some technologies and get some rewards for that. Now, these rewards are sort of like being able to create some items, get a production boost and so on.

What i am currently doing is handle flash messages and redirects in my controllers. So, imagine a case where in order to create an item, you have to have researched a specific technology. My controller would be like :

```
def create

    flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.not_researched') and redirect_to research_url and return if not current_user.has_research?(research)
    ....
    ....
end
```

Well, of course this works fine, but i'm not sure it's the best way to do things. I thought of maybe using a before_create filter to do that, but this way, i cannot really set flash messages, it's pretty much out of scope.

Therefore, i would like to ask how you would go about it in terms of best practices, so that code is as DRY as possible and as well written as it gets.

Comment: Pls let me know if I understood your question wrong- Displaying flash messages is generally done in one of the layout files that you may be using. That way it is at one central place for all views. What you havd in the controller is right. There is no need of a before_filter. Pls let me know if you need an example and I can post one. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the problem is not setting the flash messages. You could do this by having a validation in the model, and then checking if it saved in the controller.

```rb
unless research.save
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.not_researched')
  redirect_to research_url
  return
end
```

The problem in your case is that you need access to `current_user`, and this suggests that the controller is the right place to do this check.

Side note on style: I think your code would be clearer if you split that check into several lines.

```rb
unless current_user.has_research?(research)
  flash[:error] = I18n.t('error.not_researched')
  redirect_to research_url
  return
end
```

Comment: Exactly that tsherif. I would actually need current_user and more data that the validation cannot provide, correct. I'm glad that you also think that the controller seems the correct way for you as well. I actually use single liners because i've multiple checks in my controllers and i did not really want to have too many lines in an action.